# imask: can't remove consecutive whitespaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to disallow consecutive whitespaces using the [imask](https://imask.js.org/) library.

`"      This   cat is     vegan.   " - NOT OK`

`"This cat is vegan." - OK`

The following doesn't work:

```
const MaskTitle = {
  mask: /^[A-Za-z0-9.\-_/+'"&()[\]<>\s]+$/,
  prepare: (str: string) => str.toUpperCase().replace(/  +/g, ' ')
};
```

So I decided to update the 'mask' property instead - by adding **\w[ ]{2,}\w** to the expression

```
const MaskTitle = {
  mask: /^\w[ ]{2,}\w[A-Za-z0-9.\-_/+'"&()[\]<>\s]+$/, 
  prepare: (str: string) => str.toUpperCase()
};
```

Still doesn't work. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Try `mask: /^\S+(?:\s\S+)*$/` if you need to validate a string that does not have leading/trailing whitespaces and has only single whitespace between non-whitespace chunks.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate it into the existing string? I would like to keep the 'functionality' of the existing /^[A-Za-z0-9.\-_/+'"&()[\]<>\s]+$/

Comment: It is the same mechanism, but you have to take out the `\s` from the character class `^[A-Za-z0-9.\-_\/+'"&()[\]<>]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9.\-_\/+'"&()[\]<>]+)*$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird - what you've suggested doesn't work for me. I doesn't allow ANY white spaces now.

Comment: @PaxForce I think it does https://regex101.com/r/vI4UXD/1

Comment: Well, `mask: /^[A-Za-z0-9._/+'"&()[\]<>-]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9._/+'"&()[\]<>-]+)*$/` must work. Here, `\S` is replaced with `[A-Za-z0-9._/+'"&()[\]<>-]`. And the whole is equivalent of ``mask: /^[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+(?:\s[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+)*$/``

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
mask: /^[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+(?:\s[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G0YB2U/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+` - one or more letters, digits, `_` (`\w`), `.`, `/`, `+`, `'`, `"`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `<`, `>` or `-`
- `(?:\s[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `[\w./+'"&()[\]<>-]+` - one or more letters, digits, `_` (`\w`), `.`, `/`, `+`, `'`, `"`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `<`, `>` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.